# What kind of animal is Chiko?

Tags: bakemono-no-ko

The pet of Kyuuta (Ren) is a fluffy ball of hair-like animal. Though Kyuuta thinks and says it is a mouse, I didn't find anything to confirm that Chiko is a mouse.

So what animal (*if* it is an animal) is Chiko?

[image: Chiko]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Officially, Chiko is *a mysterious*, small animal.**

The [official site (Japanese)](http://www.bakemono-no-ko.jp/character/) lists Chiko as,

> チコ
> 九太と【渋谷】の路地裏で出会って以来、いつも一緒に行動している**不思議な小動物**。
>
> Chiko
> **A mysterious, small animal** that always with Kyuuta after their meeting on a back alley in "Shibuya".
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

In contrast, the official site lists some characters with their animal characteristic:

- Kumatetsu: Bear (*kuma*)
- Tatara: Old monkey
- Hyakushuubou: Slim pig

---

Out-of-universe, it looks like a *Kesaran Pasaran*, a Japanese mythical creature (*youkai*) that looks like a white fluffy furball. While it has many renditions, one of them looks like this:

[image: Random Kesaran Pasaran]

<sup>(Image posted by [Ein on Serenes Forums](https://serenesforest.net/forums/index.php?/topic/25546-do-you-want-a-kesaran-pasaran/&do=findComment&comment=1516600))</sup>

<sup>PS: I only found [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_are_Kesaran-pasaran) as the best definition in English, but it doesn't conflict with [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B1%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3).</sup>